# Secure storage - temporary per session

Tags: security, session, firefox, firefox-addon, storage

I am working on firefox addon and need to store securely some user data (no other extension, website should have access to it and data should be only stored until the browser session is closed).

Can any of you advise on the storage I should use?

If you think this is good idea to store it as files, can you point me to the direction on how to encrypt it and decrypt it in-flight?

Comment: I can only give a brief summary of how to do this (assuming add-on's are structured similar to chrome extensions): On your background page (or similar) you create your store object. Then also in your extension you pass in the values from the user (really.... encryption in JS is a false promise... best you can do is implement a detour-ant and base64 or obfuscate your code... binary even. anything else would be overkill for a insecure method) - the background pages (in chrome at least) do not allow websites to interact with them directly. This is your security measure...

Comment: So the script will take the user data, (encrypt?) it, send it to the background page that stores it in it's own context. You have other specific function to return that data (given a key?) - and because it is a var running in a background page acrossed the entire session as soon as the browser is closed the data is lost. But again, this is how I would do it in Chrome. I have to assume the extensions are similar (or am I way off there?)

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript code and the JavaScript code from some other extension are the same - telling which one is which reliably will hardly be possible. However, if you can isolate the part of your code that needs to work with the data then you can simply use JavaScript's own mechanisms. In particular, closures can access variables that no other code has access to. An example:

```js
function storeLoginData()
{
  var user = prompt("Please enter your user name");
  var pass = prompt("Please enter your password");
  return function(testUser, testPass)
  {
    return testUser == user && testPass == pass;
  };
}

var verifier = storeLoginData();
if (verifier("foo", "bar"))
  alert("Your login credentials are foo:bar");
```

Note that code outside the `storeLoginData` function can only call the closure returned but doesn't have access to its variables. In the example it is restricted to checking whether a user name/password combination is correct. And you can remove even this loophole if you make your isolated code act autonomously, on a timer or something like this:

```js
function storeData(data)
{
  var timer = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/timer;1"]
                        .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsITimer);
  timer.initWithCallback(function()
  {
    // Do something with data here
  }, 1000, timer.TYPE_ONE_SHOT);

  return function() {};
}

var data = ...;
var dataStorage = storeData(data);
data = null;
```

Note how the main code passes the `data` variable to `storeData` and nulls it out after that - all the references to the variable are now inside the `storeData` function. The closure returned here is useless and its only goal is to keep a reference to the `timer` variable - without that the timer will be garbage collected and will never fire. The security of this solution relies on the fact that there is no way to enumerate all timers in the system - this is true for timer objects but not event listeners or observers for example.

Of course, the data stays unencrypted in memory - that's hardly avoidable. Consequently, any binary code will still be able to read it, the protection works only against JavaScript.